# Creating mysql trigger gets to read timeout with no error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a new trigger that will insert data into a new table once new rows are inserted to a specific table.

I tried to extend the timeout, checking syntax, nothing indicated a problem so far, but as I'm new in creating triggers I hope this is the correct way and need some guidance.

Here is the trigger that I'm trying to create -

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `dcs`.`cb_flights_AFTER_INSERT`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `dcs`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `dcs`.`cb_flights_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `cb_flights` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE round INT(11);
   -- variable declarations

   set @round = (select r.id
    from dcs.rounds r
    join dcs.maps m
    on m.pk = r.map_fk
   where NEW.map_fk = r.map_fk 
    and NEW.era_fk = r.era_fk 
    and 
    ((NEW.takeoff_time > r.start_time and NEW.takeoff_time < r.end_time) 
    or 
    (NEW.takeoff_time > r.start_time and r.end_time is null)));

   -- trigger code
   insert into flights_rounds (flight_fk, round_fk)
   values (NEW.flight_fk, round);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

here are the relevant tables -

```
Table: cb_flights
Columns:
pk int(11) AI PK 
ucid varchar(50) 
takeoff_time datetime 
end_time datetime 
end_event varchar(45) 
side varchar(45) 
kills int(11) 
type varchar(45) 
map_fk int(11) 
era_fk int(11)

Table: rounds
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
round_id int(11) 
map_fk int(11) 
era_fk int(11) 
start_time datetime 
end_time datetime 
winner varchar(45) 
tour date

Table: maps
Columns:
pk int(11) AI PK 
map varchar(45)

Table: eras
Columns:
pk int(11) AI PK 
era varchar(45)

Table: flights_rounds
Columns:
flight_fk int(11) PK 
round_fk int(11)
```

I expect that for each inserted row in the cb_flights table, a new row will be created by a trigger in the flights_rounds table that will indicate the relevant round from the rounds table for each flight from the cb_flights table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the trigger to:

```
begin   
    insert into flights_rounds (flight_fk, round_fk)
       select NEW.flight_fk, r.id
       from dcs.rounds r join
            dcs.maps m
            on m.pk = r.map_fk
       where NEW.map_fk = r.map_fk and
             NEW.era_fk = r.era_fk and
            ((NEW.takeoff_time > r.start_time and NEW.takeoff_time < r.end_time) or
             (NEW.takeoff_time > r.start_time and r.end_time is null)
            );
end;
```

This also fixes the confusion between `round` and `@round`.

This probably won't fix the performance issue.  For that, I would recommend indexes on `rounds(map_fk, era_fk, start_time, end_time)` and `maps(pk)`.

Comment: Few issues there, there's an extra closing parenthesis and missing comma in the select.
After running this, still getting to the timeout.
The question is why is creating a trigger getting to a read timeout? does it now go through all the existing rows in the cb_flights table? isn't it suppose to only trigger in case a new row is inserted? 

both maps and rounds table are really small so there couldn't be a performance issue there.

Comment: @Morrtz . . . Did you add the index?

Comment: Added the missing start_time and end_time in rounds table, maps table had pk indexed. it now failed very quickly and showed that the issue was NEW.flight_fk which was actually NEW.pk. after fixing it, it took 5 minutes to introduce the trigger.

Comment: @Morrtz . . . There is *one* index with multiple columns, not multiple indexes.

Comment: added it aswell